# convert date from 23-08-2015 00:00:00 to Tue Aug 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530

Tags: javascript, c#, fullcalendar

I have date in `23-08-2015 00:00:00` format in my controller and pass it to view using ViewData. I want to convert this date to `Tue Aug 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530` format.. Is it possible with controller or can I convert it in my view using jquery?

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I would give Moment.js a try: http://momentjs.com

Comment: Thank u I done it  by below answer Convert.ToString(startDate.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss")) + " GMT+0530"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it by using following format:

```
 string startDateCalendar = Convert.ToString(startDate.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss")) + " GMT+0530";
```

Comment: What language is this? Is it among the tags in the question?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, if you simply create a new Date object with the string that you have, you'll get the desired format.

```
var testdate = new Date("23-08-2015 00:00:00");
console.log(testdate);
```

Output:

```
Tue Nov 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: @connexo just move to India. A simple solution :-D

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
date.ToLongDateString();
```

Comment: thanks for your time. I tried it, it returns "23 August 2015"

Answer (score 0):

using JavaScript it is like so:

```
function parseDDMMYYYY(d){
    return new Date(
       d.replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/,"$3-$2-$1 $4:$5:$6")
    )
}
parseDDMMYYYY('23-08-2015 00:00:00')
```